# Show picture from DB in HEX

Tags: android, image, kotlin, imageview

I need show a picture from Json file which is received from server.
the format is somethink like this: 0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101012C012C0000FFDB00430006040506050406060506070706080A100A0A09090A14

is any way to make picture from this String? 
i try:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val obrazek ="0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101012C01...

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val data: ByteArray = obrazek.toByteArray()

        val bm: Bitmap? = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            data,
            0, data.size )

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm)
    }
```

but its not work. 
thanks for help.

Comment: First of all welcome to SO! Second of all, it might be possible that the data you get from the DB is base64 encoded, as such you'll need to decode it first and then proceed similarly to what you're doing now

Comment: You hex decode that string to bytes. To a byte array.

Comment: Is the data in the JSON an encoded image (JPG, GIF, PNG, ...) or the raw data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly convert it to ByteArray:

```
val obrazek = "0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101012C012C0000FFDB00430006040506050406060506070706080A100A0A09090A14"
val hexString = obrazek.substringAfter("0x")
val bigInt = BigInteger(hexString, 16)
val data = bigInt.toByteArray()
```

`BigInteger` converts hexcode to integers if you set radix to 16. The integers can then be converted to bytes.

`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` results to null. Perhaps the data only contains the image pixels and not wrapped within an encoded format like PNG.

I also tried this code:

```
val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data)
buffer.rewind()
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
```

But it gives me `Buffer not large enough for pixels` error. Probably, because the hexcode you gave is not complete.